# ftp_put() very slow with little file

Tags: php, multithreading, performance, ftp

I've made a form that is waiting for a file. Once it's submitted, the file is uploaded to a remote server through the `ftp_put()` function. The problem is that it take something like 2/3 minuts.

I tried removing lines one by one to find out what's wrong and it's the call to `ftp_put()` that is taking so much time. The file is only 20Ko. Is there a way to upload the file in an other thread or something ?

EDIT :
Here is my php code.

```
  $file = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['attachment']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $remote_file = '/cv_'.$_POST['first_name'].'_'.$_POST['last_name'].'_'.strval(time()).'.'.$ext;
  $ftp_server = 'xxxxxxxxx';
  $ftp_user_name = 'xxxxxx';
  $ftp_user_pass = 'xxxxxx';

  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
  if (!ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) /* This line is taking so long */
  {
    echo "There was a problem uploading the file $file\n";
  }
  ftp_close($conn_id);
```

EDIT 2 : The file is correctly uploaded after a few minuts. The code is working fine and fast on localhost, but when it's on the production server, it starts taking a long time.

Comment: So... *why* is it taking so much time? Isn't that what you should be trying to find out?

Comment: Well I already tried... But the file is being uploaded very fast through a command in shell or ftp client.

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: You mean in PHP or to test the upload through command line or ftp client ?

I've edited my post to provide my code.

Comment: No, I mean things like looking at the FTP server's logs and/or live network traffic to see why exactly the upload is taking so long.

Comment: Oh. It's not my server, i'm working for a client, and I have no response from him yet. The strange point is that it's working fine on localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it enabling passive mode.